# What does `grep -1` do?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, man

I'm trying to make sense of the following shell command, to get a list of packages that can be updated:

```
dpkg --get-selections | xargs apt-cache policy {} | grep -1 Installed | sed -r 's/(:|Installed: |Candidate: )//' | uniq -u | tac | sed '/--/I,+1 d' | tac | sed '$d' | sed -n 1~2p
```

What does `grep -1` mean? I can find no mention of `-1` in grep's man page, or indeed anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: Would it be `grep --count`?

Comment: how do I actually grep for `-1` text?

Answer (score 5):

the `-1` option is the traditional Unix style option to indicate that you want `grep` to include `1` line of extra text per match for *context*.

If you do a `man grep` and look for the heading **Context Line Control** you find the options that follow will describe the different ways you can ask for extra lines of context.  Specifically as to your question you'll see:

```
    -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
        Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line  containing  a
        group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  With
        the -o or --only-matching option,  this  has  no  effect  and  a
        warning is given.
```

this is where the `-1` is documented (as `-NUM` where NUM is 1) so the following commands would all behave the same: `grep -1` or `grep -C 1` or `grep --context=1`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out by looking at the results. It specifies how many preceding and succeeding lines (of "context") to show for each match. So in this particular case, grep will show the previous line and the next line for each match, in addition to the matching line itself.

Comment: Did you mean this? http://imgur.com/GcNVkDr

Comment: Shown in the manpage and usage message as `-NUM` and [the info](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control) as `-num` .

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing called `grep -1`, if you go to terminal and type `grep --help` you don't find `grep -1`

Comment: You will find `-NUM`. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, let me get this straight. grep -1 is in question yes, but grep -NUM is available not the -1 right?

Comment: `NUM` can be replaced by any number, so you are allowed to use `-1`, `-2`, `-3` ... see the other correct answers.

Comment: Got you, I have never used grep command hence did man grep to get that. Thank you very much for explaining.